# Conway's Game of Life Creating Board and Turning Cells On

Tags: python, python-3.x, conways-game-of-life

I have just one (most likely) last question. From when I sent my last question, I have progressed a bit and I have coded 5/6 functions so far (1, 2, 3, 5, and 6), and function 4 is really just putting together functions 5 and 6, which is what I need help with. This is my code so far:

```
"""
Function 1: create a blank grid
input: nothing
return: a blank grid

Function 2: print a given grid
input: a grid
return: nothing

Function 3: load a pattern
input: a file name, a grid
return: nothing

Function 4: advance a grid one generation
input: a grid
return: a new grid advanced by one generation

Function 5: advance a cell one generation
input: a row, a column, a grid
return: whether the cell is alive or not (True or False)

Function 6: determine the number of living neighbors of a cell
input: a row, a column, a grid
return: the number of living neighbors of the cell

"""

living_cell = "O"
dead_cell = "-"


def create_blank_grid():
    # # line = [dead_cell for i in range(59)]
    # line = []
    # for i in range(59):
    #     line.append(dead_cell)
    #
    # # grid = [["-"] * 30 for i in range(60)]
    # line.append("\n")
    # # grid = [line for i in range(30)]

    line = []
    for i in range(59):
        line.append(dead_cell)
    line.append("\n")

    grid = []
    for j in range(30):
        grid.append(line[:])

    return grid


# print(create_blank_grid())

def print_grid(grid):
    for i in grid:
        # print(len(i))
        for j in i:
            if j == "\n":
                print(" " * (69 - 59))
            else:
                print(j, end="")


# print_grid(create_blank_grid())


def load_design(file_name, grid):
    myFile = open(file_name, "r")
    coordinates = []
    for line in myFile:
        real_line = line.split()
        row, col = real_line[0], real_line[1]
        coordinates.append((row, col))
    myFile.close()

    # turn on certain cells here

    for row, col in coordinates:
        row, col = int(row), int(col)
        # print(row, col)
        grid[row][col] = living_cell
        # print_grid(grid)

    for i in grid:
        # print(len(i))
        for j in i:
            print(j, end="")


# load_design("hertz-oscillator.in", create_blank_grid())


def num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid):
    living_neighbors_count = 0

    if grid[row][col + 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1

    if grid[row][col - 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1

    if grid[row + 1][col] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1

    if grid[row - 1][col] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1

    if grid[row + 1][col + 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1

    if grid[row + 1][col - 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1

    if grid[row - 1][col + 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1

    if grid[row - 1][col - 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1

    return living_neighbors_count


def adv_cell_one_gen(row, col, grid):
    row = int(row)
    col = int(col)
    # is alive, less than 2 alive neighbors
    if grid[row][col] == living_cell and num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid) < 2:
        return False

    # is alive, 2 or 3 alive neighbors
    if grid[row][col] == living_cell and (
            num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid) == 2 or num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid) == 3):
        return True

    # is alive, more than 4 alive neighbors
    if grid[row][col] == living_cell and num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid) > 4:
        return False
    # is dead, has 3 alive neighbors
    if grid[row][col] == dead_cell and num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid) == 3:
        return True


def adv_grid_one_gen(grid):
    # for i in range(len(grid)):
    #   for j in range(i):
    #     adv_cell_one_gen(j, i, grid)

    for i in grid:
        for j in i:
            if adv_cell_one_gen(j, i, grid) == True:
                grid[i][j] = living_cell
            else:
                grid[i][j] = dead_cell
    return grid


# print(adv_grid_one_gen(create_blank_grid()))
adv_grid_one_gen(create_blank_grid)
```

Function 1: create_blank_grid

Function 2: print_grid

Function 3: load_design

Function 4: adv_grid_one_gen

Function 5: adv_cell_one_gen

Function 6: num_living_neighbors

My question here is that when I try to run this, I get this error:
[image: ![basically, an error for making "-" an integer]

I understand that in the adv_cell_one_gen function, I made row and col into integers (with row = int(row) and col = int(col)), and that is causing the error, but if I don't do this, then I would get an index error because of indexing without integers. I think there is somewhere else that my code is fundamentally flawed and I don't know where, but I think I am at a dead end. This was my question and I hope you can help.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Your problem is a data-type mismatch; you chose a concatenation function, `join`, which is incompatible with your data storage.  This should not require over 100 lines of code to illustrate.  Keep in mind the central purpose of this site -- focus your question to a *single* issue that will be useful to later visitors.

Comment: First, if I don't use a boolean, I get an index error on the line "if grid[i][j] == 1" line, and therefore I don't know how to do it without one. As I said in another comment, I suspect my code is fundamentally flawed somewhere and that is one of the reasons I came to stack overflow for help

Comment: @Prune Sorry, would it be work if I didn't include my entire reference code, only the part I needed in the end, and just keep a link to my reference? If you respond I would be more than happy to change that.

Comment: Also, I am new to Stack Overflow and I just made my account for this problem I had. I understand that if a question gets downvoted//disliked by the community, the poster won't be able to post for a certain number of days, but I am confused why my first question was closed, downvoted 4 times, and I couldn't post for 3 days, and I have just received a ban for this questions also. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  When you have assimilated that material, feel free to ask specific questions you have about your posting privileges.

Comment: @Prune I read those articles and the intro tour, what should I do now that I have tried to make my question better?

Comment: You should follow the posting guidelines.  Your posted code fails to run; the failure is not the one you claim.  You refer us to off-site links for some of your material, which is not acceptable.  Your text wanders through several problems at different levels.  Read the articles, pick *one* problem, and post a focused question.  We are not going to lead you by the hand through fixing each of your coding problems; that is far outside the purpose of this site.

Comment: You have chosen a programming problem that is significantly beyond your current programming abilities.  You need to first learn about basic data types and data structures.  You need to learn how to write code incrementally: write a few lines and *test* it before moving on.  Back up to what you can handle; master that first, *then* move on.  Hard-code a small grid, say, 5x5, and debug `printBoard` with that.  *Then* work out how to initialize a blank board, using `printBoard` as a debugging tool.

Comment: Once you've learned to work in small, encapsulated steps, you should be able to focus well enough to post a coherent question.

Comment: It's the same feedback as before.  You posted 150 lines of code, far more than the problem warrants.  Your code does not come to the error you claim.  You have to simplify this.to a tractable question.  We need you to read and follow the posting guidelines.

Comment: @Prune could you take a look at my newest question?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because you have defined your cells as booleans:

```py
living_cell = True
dead_cell = False
```

The `''.join()` function takes the elements in a list and joins them together as a single string with whatever delimiter you define. The delimiter is whatever you put in the string immediately before you call `join()`. In this case its `''`.

`join()`  only works on an iterable full of strings. You have provided an iterable (your`line` list) but its full of booleans instead of strings.

To get past this error you have at least three options:

#### Define your cells as strings

This could be as simple as something like this:

```py
living_cell = "True"
dead_cell = "False"
```

However, I suspect this will break the rest of your code if your other functions rely on these variables being booleans to function properly.

#### Change the data type of during your call to `join`

You could use a list comprehension to change everything to strings when you call the `join()` function:

```py
print("".join([str(cell) for cell in line])
```

If all this function is trying to do is print out the board (which appears to be the case) this ought to get the job done.

Comment: If I do this, I would get the error "IndexError: list index out of range" on the line if grid[i][j] ==1, so I am not sure what to do. I suspect my code is fundamentally flawed somewhere and that is one of the reasons I came to stack overflow.

Comment: Changing the type of the objects in your list won't change the length of the list and therefore can't be responsible for creating an IndexError.

Comment: Hi! I got past that part and have updated my question since. Could you help with the updated question?

Answer (score 0):

In `"".join(line)`, line should be a list of strings.

However, if we look at your code, you are appending `living_cell` or `dead_cell`, which you declared as booleans in the first two lines. Thus, line is now a list of booleans, which  is the wrong input type.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve here, but if you just want to print the output, you can do

```
line.append(str(living_cell))
line.append(str(dead_cell))
```

Comment: Hi! Your answer is really comprehensive and it works, but I have another question now (and I updated the post). Would you mind answering it since I love the way your answers are short and sweet and are comprehensive?

Comment: For question 1, your defined board is of size 50 * 50. However, you are assuming that your board is of size 67 * 50 in you code. I'm not so sure about question 2 since I didn't run your code.